# Errors running pppd inside a docker container

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, alpine-linux, pppd

I have a docker container that I'm trying to run pppd inside of.  The host kernel has `CONFIG_PPP=y`.  I'm setting up the ppp device like this:

```
mkdir /run/container/dev
mknod /run/container/dev c 108 0
... add some more devices here ...
```

Then I'm starting the container with a volume mount of `/run/container/dev:/dev`.  The container is run with `--privileged` and processes inside the container run as root.

When I try to run pppd inside the container it fails:

```
/ # pppd
Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Operation not permitted
pppd: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support
```

`strace` suggests that the problem is `EPERM` when trying to open `/dev/ppp`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ppp", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
getpid()                                = 76
sendto(3, "<27>Jul 14 09:55:08 pppd[76]: Co"..., 89, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 ENOTCONN (Socket not connected)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 12) = -1 EPROTOTYPE (Protocol wrong type for socket)
write(1, "Couldn't open the /dev/ppp devic"..., 58Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Operation not permitted) = 58
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="pppd: Sorry - this system lacks "..., iov_len=52}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2pppd: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support

) = 52
getpid()                                = 76
sendto(3, "<27>Jul 14 09:55:08 pppd[76]: So"..., 75, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 ENOTCONN (Socket not connected)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 12) = -1 EPROTOTYPE (Protocol wrong type for socket)
exit_group(4)                           = ?
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the command or docker-compose.yaml of how you are running this docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually tracked this down to needing `--device-cgroup-rule="c 108:0 rwm"` on the docker command-line.